# How to replay the background music when I closed the new form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, wmp

The main form is form1 and I have a button1 in form1
when the button was clicked, form2 will show
I use axWindowsMediaPlayer1 to play background music and once the button1 was clicked the music will stop and show form2.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
    Form2 newForm2 = new Form2();
    newForm2.Show();
}
```

There is also a button in form2, once clicked form2 will close.
Now I can't figure out how to replay the music once I clicked the button in form2.

Comment: You should name your forms and controls.

Comment: question is not clear, share more code

Answer (score 0):

Start your music within [FormClosed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) event. It will trigger your code when the form will be closed.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
    Form2 newForm2 = new Form2();
    newForm2.FormClosed += (s, e) => axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.Start();
    newForm2.Show();
}
```

Comment: It worked, exactly what I'm looking for, thank you so much.